# Grafana with MySQL: this authentication plugin is not supported

Tags: mysql, grafana

I am trying to load some data from MySQL to Grafana, but got the following error. Any idea what I missed? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its happends couse **grafana** don't maintain the new mysql authorization method named `caching_sha2_password`. Sinse **mysql 8** its default setting.
To solve this problem you need just to create new user with `mysql_native_password` authentication plugin connector.

#### Step 1. Check the available users and its plugins.

```
MySQL [localhost+ ssl] SQL> select user, plugin from mysql.user;
+------------------+-----------------------+
| user             | plugin                |
+------------------+-----------------------+
| pi               | caching_sha2_password |
| mysql.infoschema | caching_sha2_password |
| mysql.session    | caching_sha2_password |
| mysql.sys        | caching_sha2_password |
| root             | caching_sha2_password |
+------------------+-----------------------+
6 rows in set (0.0011 sec)
```

All the users has `caching_sha2_password` authorization plugin.

#### Step 2. Open the mysql workbench and connect to database.

Execute the query

```
CREATE USER 'native_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password;
```

The result must be like this one

```
09:30:17    CREATE USER 'native_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password 0 row(s) affected   0.156 sec
```

#### Step 3. In mysql workbench open server -> users and privilegas

Select native_user form the list. **Change the password, default shema and shema privilegas for this user.** Save the changes.

#### Step 4. Check with mysql shell

```
MySQL [localhost+ ssl] SQL> select user, plugin from mysql.user ;
+------------------+-----------------------+
| user             | plugin                |
+------------------+-----------------------+
| pi               | caching_sha2_password |
| mysql.infoschema | caching_sha2_password |
| mysql.session    | caching_sha2_password |
| mysql.sys        | caching_sha2_password |
| native_user      | mysql_native_password |
| root             | caching_sha2_password |
+------------------+-----------------------+
6 rows in set (0.0011 sec)
```

#### Step 5. Open the grafana datasouces and set up new user.

Good luck!

P.S. I cant create a new user with `mysql_native_password` using mysql workbanch. Maybe its bug. Use command prompt instead.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. Below works as well. No need to create a new user.

```
select user,plugin from mysql.user;
alter user root@'localhost' identified with mysql_native_password by 'my_password';
select user,plugin from mysql.user;
```